# To copy files each minute at /var/www without sudo

Tags: unix, sudo, cp

**How can you copy a folder to /var/www without sudo?**

My folder `codes` has the following permissions at /var/www

```
4 drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 2009-08-09 03:01 codes
```

I can only `sudo cp -r ~/Dropbox/codes/ /var/www` to copy the files.
I cannot copy them without sudo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Owning `/var/www` yourself might conflict with other options on your system.  On my Debian system I would do this

```
sudo addgroup www
sudo adduser nr www   # add myself to the www group
sudo chgrp -R www /var/www  # make files in the group
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod g+w '{}' ';'  # make each file group writable
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+ws '{}' ';' # make each directory group writable and sticky
```

If the directory is group writable and sticky, all files created in `/var/www` will be writable by anyone in the `www` group, no matter who or what creates them there.  (Caveat: they have to be created by "normal" means; `cp -a` can circumvent the group sticky bit.)

Because Unix is insanely stupid about group membership, for your membership to be honored you will have to log in again, e.g., `ssh localhost` or log out and log back in.  A nuisance.

Comment: Although the other answers will work this one is the correct way. +1

Comment: I run `cp -r codes /var/www/ unsuccessfully in getting a long list of the following errors `cp: cannot create regular file /var/www/codes/index.php': Permission denied`. This suggests me that something else need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding the cron job to the root user. It's not a great idea, but it will get around the problem?

I also find it interesting that your www directory would have only root permissions and be owned by root. Usually they are owned by an apache user or have other permissions such that apache can access them.

**Edit** You probably don't want to edit the crontab file directy. But something similar to the following command should work:

```
sudo crontab -e -u root
```

You may not need the `-u root` but it's good so sudo doesn't confuse crontab.

**Edit 2** You can change permissions with the `chmod` and `chown` commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 /path
sudo chown user:user /path
```

Be very very careful when using this. You can completely screw up the OS by changing permissions on the wrong files or folders. You'll probably want to add the -R option which will apply the permissions or owner recursively, but again, be very careful.

Comment: How can you do that? - I run unsuccessfully `sudo -i`; vim /etc/crontab`. I add the following to the file `1  *    * * *   root    sudo cp -r /home/masi/Dropbox/codes/ /var/www/`

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown yourusername /var/www
```

And you'll become the new owner of `/var/www`.

Comment: Each file inside the /var/www/codes is owned by root. Does the following command allow me to copy `sudo chown /var/www/codes/*`?

Comment: `chown -R` for recursive `chown`.

Comment: This is not a good idea and can cause problems with other users and even apache its self.