# How to resolve /var/www copy/write permission denied?

Tags: unix, permissions, cp

I am a newbie in php, mysql. I have written a hello.php script, which I am trying to copy into /var/www directory (and will later want to open it through web browser). The problem with the same is that I am not allowed to save/write any files in /var/www despite me being the root. I tried implementing steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250231/to-copy-files-each-minute-at-var-www-without-sudo) question, but I get the following error when I process the third line

```
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod g+w '{}' ';'
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/index.html': Operation not permitted
```

I know symlink is also an option. I would want to be able to write/copy files directly to /var/www/ directory.

Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

it'matter of *unix permissions, gain root acces, for example by typing

```
sudo su
[then type your password]
```

and try to do what you have to do

Answer (score 15):

Do you have a file in `/var/www` called hello.php already that has permissions on it? Maybe the system can't replace the file?

Although, root access should supersede any user on the system.

Have you tried applying permissions to the `www` folder?

If you can do this, try the following:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

then do:

`sudo cp hello.php /var/www`

I only recommend doing this if you know 100% that it is ok to set permissions on the whole `www` folder. By the sounds of it, you are running on your own production server as most live/shared hosting servers are setup so that the `www` folder is not in the /var folder (instead it is in the home folder of the user).

Be VERY careful when doing anything with the sudo prefix though, you can seriously damage your system if you do it wrong.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Are you in a development environment ? If Yes, You can do

```
chown -R user:group /var/www
```

so you will be able to write with your user.

Comment: Good idea, but the correct syntax is `# chown -R newuser:newgroup /var/www` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

Answer (score 12):

Execute the following command

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:<user_name>:rwx /var/www
```

It will change the permissions of html directory so that you can upload, download and delete the files or directories

Answer (score 2):

Encountered a similar problem today.  Did not see my fix listed here, so I thought I'd share.

Root could not erase a file.

I did my research.  Turns out there's something called an immutable bit.

```
# lsattr /path/file
----i-------- /path/file
#
```

This bit being configured prevents even root from modifying/removing it.

To remove this I did:

```
# chattr -i /path/file
```

After that I could rm the file.

In reverse, it's a neat trick to know if you have something you want to keep from being gone.

:)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, this has nothing to do with php. This is a unix permission issue. You need to login as a superuser ( sudo/su ) and type your password, then try that command.

```
$ su
(type password )
\# your command

$ sudo command
$ (type password)
```

It might also help if you actually specified the operating system you use.

Comment: @meder: im using ubuntu. and i have tried using $sudo command as mentioned by phoebus.

Comment: Are you prompted for a password? How about copy pasting *EVERYTHING* you tried?

Comment: Do you share the computer? Is your user setup as a sudoer?

Comment: Did you try 'su' as the first thing in the code snippet I have? This will let you run as a superuser permanently for the session.

Comment: @meder: that works. can you please tell me why I am supposed to work as superuser for the same? is a 'default' permission issue for /var/www/ directory?

Comment: You aren't supposed to work as a superuser, but it's probably better off if you change the ownership of /var/www/ so your user owns it. As superuser, do chown -R shubster:shubster /var/www and then log in as yourself and work on files as that username, not as root.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp hello.php /var/www/
```

What output do you get?

Comment: @phoebus: output is 'cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/hello.php': Permission denied'

Comment: cd /var  
ls -l  
what are the permissions next to www?

Comment: that's two commands, cd /var and ls -l.  Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @edorian Thanks so much for the admonishment on on of my first posts three years after the fact :)

Comment: @phoebus The answer was picked up by the new automated review beta tool and that left the comment in my name. I assume to let future visitors know :) I didn't look at the date to be honest as all the questions and answers it marked for review had to be put in categories :)

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works, you might be dealing with a vfat filesystem.  Use "df" to check.

See http://www.charlesmerriam.com/blog/2009/12/operation-not-permitted-and-the-fat-32-system/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to login as root and than go to /etc directory and execute some commands which are given below.

```
[root@localhost~]# cd /etc
[root@localhost /etc]# vi sudoers
```

and enter this line at the end

```
kundan ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

where kundan is the username and than save it. and then try to transfer the file and add `sudo` as a prefix to the command you want to execute:

```
sudo cp hello.txt /home/rahul/program/
```

where rahul is the second user in the same server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please do not use short-form texting notations (such as 'u' for 'you') in your answers.  Also note how indenting text by 4 spaces yields the highlighted computer-font notation.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write `sudo` instead of `su`.

Then just copy the PHP file to the `var/www/ directory`.

Then go to the browser, and write local `host/test.php` or whatever the `.php` filename is.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command in the directory you want to modify the right:

for example the directory: `/var/www/html`

```
sudo setfacl -m g:username:rwx . #-> for file

sudo setfacl -d -m g:username: rwx . #-> for directory
```

This will solve the problem.

Replace username with your username.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a privilege issue navigate to the var/www/
right-click in it and select open as admin
then continue your work