# Rails issue on cap production deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

My stack is Puma + Nginx + PostgreSQL, on AWS EC2. I'm using Capistrano 3.4 to deploy a Rails 4.2.4 app. I've been stabbing in the dark trying to solve this for a while now so thought I'd see if I can get some help to shed some light on this issue. It's not conceptually difficult, I just don't know why what I've tried doesn't work.

Here's what the Capistrano output says:

```
...
DEBUG [f85d7a84] Command: cd /home/deploy/my_app/releases/20151210184710 && ( export RVM_BIN_PATH="~/.rvm/bin" aws_access_key_id="<MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>" aws_secret_access_key="<MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>"  RAILS_ENV="production" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/deploy/my_app/releases/20151210184710/Gemfile'.
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    
DEBUG [f85d7a84]    ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
...
```

Notice in the first line there has been some attempt in the Bash command to set the required arguments, but clearly they can't be accessed in the `rake assets:precompile`. So my problem is how to set the 'required arguments' aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key correctly.

What I've tried:

1) Setting them in config/deploy.rb (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602548/capistrano-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-the-whole-cap-session))

To do this I used:

```
set :default_env, {
  rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin',
  'aws_access_key_id' => '<MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>',
  'aws_secret_access_key' => '<MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
 }
```

2) Setting them on my EC2 server in shared/secrets.yml: (Inspired by [this](https://gorails.com/forum/ruby-issue-when-doing-cap-deploy-production))

```
aws_access_key_id: '<MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>',
aws_secret_access_key: '<MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
```

I linked to these in config/deploy.rb as

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml secrets.yml}
```

Currently this is how I'm trying to input the keys in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      #:aws_access_key_id     => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], # I still get the same error when I use these two lines instead
      #:aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      :aws_access_key_id     => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
      :aws_secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key
    }
    config.fog_directory    = ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']
end
```

3) Setting them in config/application.yml (inspired by [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/)) as

```
aws_access_key_id: "<MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>"
aws_secret_access_key: "<MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>"
```

So why aren't any of these methods working? I'm not very experienced at setting environment variables let alone on a remote server but I've seen threads/blog posts where each of these seem to work.

Thanks for your help everyone. Feel free to ask questions or for more info!

Comment: Have you tried setting manually outside like 1) or 2) in the answer in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457422/amazon-ses-error-retrieving-credentials-from-the-instance-profile-metadata-serve/33479906#33479906

Comment: 1) Set the environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION with the values from the IAM profile you created.

Comment: 2) Instead of 1), you can also create ~/.aws/credentials file. Here you can add the lines: 
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
aws_default_region = the region

Comment: If you are running your code on linux. you just need to do 'export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=value' on the shell. do it for all 3 env vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues with your options, I'll list them accordingly below:

1. Environment variable names are case-sensitive which means you are exporting for example `aws_access_key_id`, but from you carrierwave code you are referencing `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']`.

   Read more about [assigning environment variables here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Assignment).
2. Your capistrano is trying to link `secrets.yml`, what you actually need is `config/secrets.yml`, try changing that line to:

   `set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml config/secrets.yml}`
3. Assuming you have installed the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) as mentioned in the post referred, I assume (based on the details you provided) the issue will most likely be related to case-sensitivity (goto 1.)

Pick one and give it another go!

Comment: Like you say 1. was the right way. I was getting confused because the error mentions them in lower case, but of course the carrierwave initializer takes them into lower case variables from the upper case environment vars. I thought I had tried them capitalized them anyway, but I just gave it another go and now it works! Really appreciate this.